# MAX() vs ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

```
   INSERT INTO counters (REQUEST_ID, MODIFIED_DATE_WFM) 
SELECT 
si_id, MAX(modified_date) AS field 
FROM tt 
group by si_id
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
MODIFIED_DATE_WFM = VALUES(modified_date)
```

ERROR SQL (1054): Unknown column 'modified_date' in 'field list'

i`m tried use sub queries:

```
select * from (SELECT 
    si_id, MAX(modified_date) AS field 
    FROM tt 
    group by si_id) sub1
```

and alias:

```
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
MODIFIED_DATE_WFM = VALUES(field)
```

But select:

```
SELECT 
    si_id, MAX(modified_date) AS field 
    FROM tt 
    group by si_id
```

is work

**FOR TEST:**
FITS TABLE:

```
 CREATE TABLE `counters` (
        `REQUEST_ID` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `MODIFIED_DATE_WFM` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        UNIQUE INDEX `REQUEST_ID` (`REQUEST_ID`)
    )
    COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    ;
```

SECOND TABLE :

```
CREATE TABLE `tt` (
    `si_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `modified_date` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    INDEX `si_id` (`si_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

DATA:

```
INSERT INTO `tt` VALUES (2574604, 1486086672);
INSERT INTO `tt` VALUES (2574604, 1487116221);
INSERT INTO `tt` VALUES (2574604, 1487971423);
INSERT INTO `tt` VALUES (2574604, 1488136028);
INSERT INTO `tt` VALUES (2574604, 1488136324);
INSERT INTO `tt` VALUES (2574604, 1488524248);
INSERT INTO `tt` VALUES (2574604, 1488728989);
INSERT INTO `tt` VALUES (2834403, 1488782168);
```

Server version: 5.7.16 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: So, `counters` table does not have the `MODIFIED_DATE` column. That's what exactly the error reports you. Btw, it does not have the `id` column either.

Comment: `INSERT INTO counters (REQUEST_ID, MODIFIED_DATE_WFM) ...` &c.

Comment: @baao it would be a "typo" if they typed `MODIFIED_DATE_WFN`

Comment: Sorry my fail check again, im fixed  name column  in INSERT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update in on update is wrong. Try it with this:

```
INSERT INTO counters (REQUEST_ID, MODIFIED_DATE_WFM) 
SELECT 
si_id, MAX(modified_date) AS `field` 
FROM tt 
group by si_id
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
MODIFIED_DATE_WFM = VALUES(MODIFIED_DATE_WFM);
```

Check here: http://rextester.com/MCR40199

Comment: But how =) its imposible ) may be its bug ?

Comment: The values() expects a column of the insert statement. Not very logical in this case, but it is like it is :-)) @VladimirLenkov

Comment: English is not my native language, I would describe it as the stuff that has been selected for insertion will be used in VALUES(), don't know if that description makes it more logical... @VladimirLenkov