# Trigger auto-incrementing composite key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, conditional-statements

Just wanted to auto-increment one of primary keys included in composite key if other primary key already exists. There are few examples on Stack but somehow I can't obtain proper query using MySQL syntax. This is how it should work:

```
operation_table:
    operation_id | client_name
               1 |           A
               1 |           B
               2 |           A
               3 |           A
               4 |           A
               2 |           B
```

and this is what to fulfill:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER operation_id_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON operation_table
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN

...

END; //
```

Going to be grateful for the help. It has already taken me a lot of time and still I can't go further.

Comment: There are no primary keys or auto_increment columns here. What you seem to be saying is if I get a duplicate name increment the id for that name by 1?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is

> INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement

SEE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

This would be triggered when the composite key restrictions would be violatd

Comment: Thanks! In my DB it's also possible to delete operations, so it could lead to ,,missincrementation". I should prevent these situations writing statement like "operation_id=(SELECT MAX(operation_id) FROM daily_operation WHERE client_id = ?)+1" but it thows me error ,,You can' t specify target table 'operation_table' for update in FROM clause". What is the best way to omit the error? Declaring maxid value before inserting a row?

Comment: I really don't think that "missincrementation" is that bad, because that happens all the time, that only think is that the rules are not violated. You colud build an sert statement with a dummy Column where you store the max value, and then use that to update the id column. similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842842/max-vs-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 0):

A way to build your own 'auto_increment' is to have a table which you can access and update) in your trigger for example

```
    drop table if exists t,t1;
    create table t
    (    operation_id int, client_name varchar(1));
    create table t1
    (next_operation_id int,client_name varchar(1));

    drop trigger if exists t;
    delimiter $$
    create trigger t before insert on t
    for each row 
    begin
        if exists(select 1 from t1 where t1.client_name = new.client_name) then
            set new.operation_id = (select next_operation_id from t1 where t1.client_name = new.client_name);
            update t1
                set next_operation_id = (next_operation_id + 1)
                where t1.client_name = new.client_name; 
        else
            set new.operation_id = 1;
            insert into t1 values(2,new.client_name);
        end if;
    end $$
    delimiter ;

    truncate table t;
    truncate table t1;
    insert into t (client_name) values 
    (                          'A'),
    (                          'B'),
    (                          'A'),
    (                          'A'),
    (                          'A'),
    (                          'B');


    select * from t;

+--------------+-------------+
| operation_id | client_name |
+--------------+-------------+
|            1 | A           |
|            1 | B           |
|            2 | A           |
|            3 | A           |
|            4 | A           |
|            2 | B           |
+--------------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    select * from t1;

+-------------------+-------------+
| next_operation_id | client_name |
+-------------------+-------------+
|                 5 | A           |
|                 3 | B           |
+-------------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```